# How to get file in Android outside Activity class using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a `RecipeListActivity` which has a RecyclerView and a `DataManager.kt` singleton in which I have the recipes stored in a HashMap. I need to read those recipes from a .xml file.

I managed to access it from The `RecipeListActivity` using `assets.open`, however I need to access them in the DataManager class and I can't use `assets.open` there.

So in my DataManager class I have the following function which runs on `init()`.

```
private fun seedRecipes() {
    val parser = XmlPullParserHandler()
    val istream = File("recipes.xml").inputStream()
    recipes = parser.parse(istream)
}
```

However I get:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   recipes.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)

It doesn't matter where the .xml file is located, I just want to access it. 
What are some ways to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I see ``assets.open`` I assume this file is part of your app's resources? This is something totally different as having the file on the file system of the device running the app.
why not pass a context to the function so you can use resources as normal?
Another approach would be that the activity saves the xml temporary to your app's /files folder where you can then open it.

Comment: You still wouldn't be able to open the file without a `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access local or internal files without a Context instance. You should pass your DataManager class a Context to use in its constructor. Then you can get your resources or assets with `context.resources` or `context.assets`.

```
class DataManager(private val context: Context) {

    //...

    init {
        seedRecipes()
    }

    private fun seedRecipes() {
        recipes = context.assets.open("locations.xml").use {
            XmlPullParserHandler().parse(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, input streams have to be closed, which you didn't do in your example. The `use` function automatically closes a stream for you after its lambda returns.